# scrapy xpath selectors return none

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to re-write code that I created using the requests-html library. Due to extra features required for the project I'm now using scrapy.

I'm having difficulty getting the scrapy/splash spider to fetch the xpaths. Each time I run the code I get none back.

With requests-html the xpaths return the data desired.

**requests-html code:**

```
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession, HTMLSession

asession = AsyncHTMLSession()

async def get_page():
    code = 'NASDAQ-MDB'
    r = await asession.get(f'https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/{code}/')
    await r.html.arender(wait=4)
    return r

results = asession.run(get_page)
for result in results:
    enterprise_value_sel = "(//span[@class='tv-widget-fundamentals__value apply-overflow-tooltip'])[2]"
    total_shares_outstanding_sel = "(//span[@class='tv-widget-fundamentals__value apply-overflow-tooltip'])[4]"

    enterprise_value = result.html.xpath(enterprise_value_sel, first=True).text
    total_shares_outstanding = result.html.xpath(total_shares_outstanding_sel, first=True).text
    print(enterprise_value, total_shares_outstanding)
```

**scrapy_splash_code:**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
import json
from tradingview.items import *
import datetime
import os

class TradingviewsigsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name ='tradingviewsigs'

    script = """
            function main(splash, args)
                assert(splash:go(args.url))
                assert(splash:wait(5.5))
                local scroll_to =splash:jsfunc("window.scrollTo")
                scroll_to(0, 800)
                return {
                    html =splash:html(),
                    png =splash:png(),
                    har =splash:har(),
                }
        end
    """
    start_urls =['https://tradingview.com/symbols/NASDAQ-MDB/']

    def start_requests(self):

        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url=url,
                                callback=self.parse,
                                endpoint='execute',
                                args={'lua_source': self.script})

    def parse(self, response):
        url = response.url
        print('Crawling: < {} >'.format(url))

        financials = TradingviewItem()
        financials['enterprise_val_sel'] = response.xpath("(//span[@class='tv-widget-fundamentals__value apply-overflow-tooltip'])[2]/text()").extract_first()
        financials['total_shares_outstanding_sel'] = response.xpath("(//span[@class='tv-widget-fundamentals__value apply-overflow-tooltip'])[4]/text()").extract_first()
        yield financials
```

What do I need to do to make the xpaths compatible with scrapy?

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix your XPath accordingly (use `()` and `[position]` to select what you need) :

```
(//span[@class='tv-widget-fundamentals__value apply-overflow-tooltip'])[2]
(//span[@class='tv-widget-fundamentals__value apply-overflow-tooltip'])[4]
```

Output : 9.334B - 57.566M